# Can we add address of integer in this manner

Tags: c

Is it possible to add an address of an integer in this manner?

```
int i = 10;
(&i)++;
```

If I try this,C Compiler is giving an error: `lvalue required as increment operand` .
Can any one suggest if it is possible with GCC or not ?

Comment: What do you expect such an expression to do?

Comment: WHY? That's the question...

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that.  `&i` yields an rvalue, which can't be used with the `++` operator, just as the compiler is telling you.  If you want to point to the memory just past the end of `i`, you can use:

```
int i = 10;
int *p = &i + 1;
```

But there's not really any reason to do such a thing.